# MySQL 5.5 innoDB writes drop, scripts slow down and locks increase

Tags: mysql

I have a database that I do INSERTS into by a python script that calls various API's and runs on a cron. There are also SELECT statements that look at previous values in the table in order to create averages based off the current and previous data.

Everything runs fine for a day or two, however after that the database seems to enter a form of contention where the sites will drop, locks will increase and the scripts slow down in their performance. I do deletes after all scripts complete (Never at the same time to avoid locking) in order to truncate data and keep the database small ensuring it doesn't reach it's `buffer_pool_size` limit.

Previously I had a crazy `query_cache_size` of `2048M` for a DB that is heavy on writes, I've changed that to `10M` recently and the `query_cache_limit` to `256K` since then I've done no extra changes.

There are a lot of mixed reviews online about what can be done to optimise this, most of my tables have an index because it is also heavy on SELECT statements as well as writes.

The below is my `my.cnf` file, I'm hoping someone might be able to help with if there's any setting here that might be ubsurd and should be changed. I'm running on `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.62, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)` and using innoDB. Below is the `my.cnf` file. Appreciate the help.

`thread_cache_size` was set to 100 as `max_used_connections` tends to sit on 128. `Threads_connected` tends to range from 90-120.

The server is a 4-core 32gb RAM server from AWS r5.xlarge

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.

[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
host        = 127.0.0.1

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.

[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.pid #/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock #/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp

lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking

#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.

bind-address        = 0.0.0.0

key_buffer_size = 256M
table_cache = 16394

thread_cache_size       = 100
innodb_file_per_table       = ON

## Per-Thread Buffers * (max_connections) = total per-thread mem usage
thread_stack            = 256K    #default: 32bit: 192K, 64bit: 256K
sort_buffer_size        = 2M      #default: 2M, larger may cause perf issues
read_buffer_size        = 2M      #default: 128K, change in increments of 4K
read_rnd_buffer_size    = 2M      #default: 256K
join_buffer_size        = 2M      #default: 128K
binlog_cache_size       = 256K    #default: 32K, size of buffer to hold TX queries

## Query Cache
query_cache_size        = 10M     #global buffer
query_cache_limit       = 256K    #max query result size to put in cache

## Connections
max_connections         = 500 # was 400   #multiplier for memory usage via per-thread buffers
max_connect_errors      = 100 # was 200   #default: 10
concurrent_insert       = 2       #default: 1, 2: enable insert for all instances
connect_timeout         = 60      #default -5.1.22: 5, +5.1.22: 10

## Table and TMP settings
max_heap_table_size         = 2048M #recommend same size as tmp_table_size
bulk_insert_buffer_size     = 2048M #recommend same size as tmp_table_size
tmp_table_size              = 2048M    #recommend 1G min

## MyISAM Engine
key_buffer          = 2M    #global buffer
myisam_sort_buffer_size     = 256M  #index buffer size for creating/altering indexes
myisam_max_sort_file_size   = 512M  #max file size for tmp table when creating/alering indexes

## InnoDB IO settings -  5.5.x and greater
innodb_write_io_threads     = 64 # Apr7
innodb_read_io_threads      = 64 # Apr7
#innodb_log_file_size       = 3G

innodb_buffer_pool_size     = 22G           #global buffer
innodb-buffer-pool-instances    = 20
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 24M           #global buffer


# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!

#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#

log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log

#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries   = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.

#server-id      = 1
#log_bin            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
#binlog_do_db       = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db   = include_database_name

#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Complete GLOBAL STATUS after the servers been up for over 24 hours and has now hit the contention state.

```
Variable_name   Value
Aborted_clients 8659
Aborted_connects    0
Binlog_cache_disk_use   0
Binlog_cache_use    0
Binlog_stmt_cache_disk_use  0
Binlog_stmt_cache_use   0
Bytes_received  10528823106
Bytes_sent  11879095113
Com_admin_commands  114321
Com_assign_to_keycache  0
Com_alter_db    0
Com_alter_db_upgrade    0
Com_alter_event 0
Com_alter_function  0
Com_alter_procedure 0
Com_alter_server    0
Com_alter_table 0
Com_alter_tablespace    0
Com_analyze 0
Com_begin   0
Com_binlog  0
Com_call_procedure  0
Com_change_db   2494
Com_change_master   0
Com_check   0
Com_checksum    0
Com_commit  21669803
Com_create_db   0
Com_create_event    0
Com_create_function 0
Com_create_index    0
Com_create_procedure    0
Com_create_server   0
Com_create_table    0
Com_create_trigger  0
Com_create_udf  0
Com_create_user 0
Com_create_view 0
Com_dealloc_sql 0
Com_delete  57847
Com_delete_multi    2
Com_do  0
Com_drop_db 0
Com_drop_event  0
Com_drop_function   0
Com_drop_index  0
Com_drop_procedure  0
Com_drop_server 0
Com_drop_table  0
Com_drop_trigger    0
Com_drop_user   0
Com_drop_view   0
Com_empty_query 0
Com_execute_sql 0
Com_flush   1
Com_grant   0
Com_ha_close    0
Com_ha_open 0
Com_ha_read 0
Com_help    0
Com_insert  10384315
Com_insert_select   4493
Com_install_plugin  0
Com_kill    0
Com_load    0
Com_lock_tables 0
Com_optimize    0
Com_preload_keys    0
Com_prepare_sql 0
Com_purge   0
Com_purge_before_date   0
Com_release_savepoint   0
Com_rename_table    0
Com_rename_user 0
Com_repair  0
Com_replace 0
Com_replace_select  0
Com_reset   0
Com_resignal    0
Com_revoke  0
Com_revoke_all  0
Com_rollback    0
Com_rollback_to_savepoint   0
Com_savepoint   0
Com_select  31617317
Com_set_option  585637
Com_signal  0
Com_show_authors    0
Com_show_binlog_events  0
Com_show_binlogs    0
Com_show_charsets   0
Com_show_collations 0
Com_show_contributors   0
Com_show_create_db  0
Com_show_create_event   0
Com_show_create_func    0
Com_show_create_proc    0
Com_show_create_table   0
Com_show_create_trigger 0
Com_show_databases  1
Com_show_engine_logs    0
Com_show_engine_mutex   0
Com_show_engine_status  4415
Com_show_events 0
Com_show_errors 0
Com_show_fields 7780
Com_show_function_status    0
Com_show_grants 0
Com_show_keys   0
Com_show_master_status  0
Com_show_open_tables    0
Com_show_plugins    0
Com_show_privileges 0
Com_show_procedure_status   0
Com_show_processlist    0
Com_show_profile    0
Com_show_profiles   0
Com_show_relaylog_events    0
Com_show_slave_hosts    0
Com_show_slave_status   0
Com_show_status 4416
Com_show_storage_engines    0
Com_show_table_status   0
Com_show_tables 2492
Com_show_triggers   0
Com_show_variables  9040
Com_show_warnings   11880457
Com_slave_start 0
Com_slave_stop  0
Com_stmt_close  48226
Com_stmt_execute    90467
Com_stmt_fetch  0
Com_stmt_prepare    48354
Com_stmt_reprepare  0
Com_stmt_reset  0
Com_stmt_send_long_data 218
Com_truncate    16
Com_uninstall_plugin    0
Com_unlock_tables   0
Com_update  11304832
Com_update_multi    0
Com_xa_commit   0
Com_xa_end  0
Com_xa_prepare  0
Com_xa_recover  0
Com_xa_rollback 0
Com_xa_start    0
Compression ON
Connections 692888
Created_tmp_disk_tables 969524
Created_tmp_files   152
Created_tmp_tables  1104523
Delayed_errors  0
Delayed_insert_threads  0
Delayed_writes  0
Flush_commands  1
Handler_commit  74944534
Handler_delete  9802964
Handler_discover    0
Handler_prepare 0
Handler_read_first  333333
Handler_read_key    61866586
Handler_read_last   3454093
Handler_read_next   13704879326
Handler_read_prev   2773935641
Handler_read_rnd    39932346
Handler_read_rnd_next   9899032663
Handler_rollback    170160
Handler_savepoint   0
Handler_savepoint_rollback  0
Handler_update  40464627
Handler_write   180607735
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data   768282
Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data   12587532288
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty  10741
Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_dirty  175980544
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed    39908997
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free   563241
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc   110237
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total  1441760
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_rnd   0
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead   24195
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_evicted   0
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests    61256179019
Innodb_buffer_pool_reads    519946
Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free    0
Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests   307699280
Innodb_data_fsyncs  22277830
Innodb_data_pending_fsyncs  1
Innodb_data_pending_reads   0
Innodb_data_pending_writes  0
Innodb_data_read    10761654272
Innodb_data_reads   656718
Innodb_data_writes  59599294
Innodb_data_written 1327119237120
Innodb_dblwr_pages_written  39909506
Innodb_dblwr_writes 2757000
Innodb_have_atomic_builtins ON
Innodb_log_waits    0
Innodb_log_write_requests   22935831
Innodb_log_writes   16721934
Innodb_os_log_fsyncs    16783015
Innodb_os_log_pending_fsyncs    1
Innodb_os_log_pending_writes    0
Innodb_os_log_written   19349207552
Innodb_page_size    16384
Innodb_pages_created    111573
Innodb_pages_read   656709
Innodb_pages_written    39909506
Innodb_row_lock_current_waits   0
Innodb_row_lock_time    78010
Innodb_row_lock_time_avg    84
Innodb_row_lock_time_max    3217
Innodb_row_lock_waits   926
Innodb_rows_deleted 9802964
Innodb_rows_inserted    10494572
Innodb_rows_read    25829527401
Innodb_rows_updated 13355863
Innodb_truncated_status_writes  0
Key_blocks_not_flushed  0
Key_blocks_unused   1674
Key_blocks_used 21
Key_read_requests   358190032
Key_reads   0
Key_write_requests  116148559
Key_writes  0
Last_query_cost 0.000000
Max_used_connections    247
Not_flushed_delayed_rows    0
Open_files  48
Open_streams    0
Open_table_definitions  325
Open_tables 597
Opened_files    3878714
Opened_table_definitions    341
Opened_tables   620
Performance_schema_cond_classes_lost    0
Performance_schema_cond_instances_lost  0
Performance_schema_file_classes_lost    0
Performance_schema_file_handles_lost    0
Performance_schema_file_instances_lost  0
Performance_schema_locker_lost  0
Performance_schema_mutex_classes_lost   0
Performance_schema_mutex_instances_lost 0
Performance_schema_rwlock_classes_lost  0
Performance_schema_rwlock_instances_lost    0
Performance_schema_table_handles_lost   0
Performance_schema_table_instances_lost 0
Performance_schema_thread_classes_lost  0
Performance_schema_thread_instances_lost    0
Prepared_stmt_count 128
Qcache_free_blocks  0
Qcache_free_memory  0
Qcache_hits 0
Qcache_inserts  0
Qcache_lowmem_prunes    0
Qcache_not_cached   0
Qcache_queries_in_cache 0
Qcache_total_blocks 0
Queries 88430604
Questions   88219702
Rpl_status  AUTH_MASTER
Select_full_join    3100
Select_full_range_join  806
Select_range    14288643
Select_range_check  0
Select_scan 225040
Slave_heartbeat_period  0.000
Slave_open_temp_tables  0
Slave_received_heartbeats   0
Slave_retried_transactions  0
Slave_running   OFF
Slow_launch_threads 0
Slow_queries    18
Sort_merge_passes   147
Sort_range  7993917
Sort_rows   23603619
Sort_scan   934553
Ssl_accept_renegotiates 0
Ssl_accepts 0
Ssl_callback_cache_hits 0
Ssl_cipher  
Ssl_cipher_list 
Ssl_client_connects 0
Ssl_connect_renegotiates    0
Ssl_ctx_verify_depth    0
Ssl_ctx_verify_mode 0
Ssl_default_timeout 0
Ssl_finished_accepts    0
Ssl_finished_connects   0
Ssl_session_cache_hits  0
Ssl_session_cache_misses    0
Ssl_session_cache_mode  NONE
Ssl_session_cache_overflows 0
Ssl_session_cache_size  0
Ssl_session_cache_timeouts  0
Ssl_sessions_reused 0
Ssl_used_session_cache_entries  0
Ssl_verify_depth    0
Ssl_verify_mode 0
Ssl_version 
Table_locks_immediate   67102620
Table_locks_waited  0
Tc_log_max_pages_used   0
Tc_log_page_size    0
Tc_log_page_waits   0
Threads_cached  58
Threads_connected   102
Threads_created 674
Threads_running 5
Uptime  84415
Uptime_since_flush_status   84415
```

Comment: Have you got a `show global status` handy. How about enabling your slow query log and see what bad index use is happening. `0` is a good size for `query_cache_size` / `query_cache_limit` especially on a write heavy load. It introduces high contention on reads which is why it was removed in 8.0.

Comment: @danblack thanks for your message mate, I just added the current GLOBAL STATUS though I did a restart so it isn't in it's "bad" state yet. Will update again afterward when it goes bad. Thanks for your input on the `query_cache_size` and `query_cache_limit` I did read up on that in other places. I'll give it a go and see how it performs and implement the slow query log.

Comment: You also can setup the query cache to demand with **query_cache_type=DEMAND** then you can specify witch query goes into the cache. And you are the only they can know if a write to the table comes before the cache is used. see also the slow query lock like @danblack has wrote. htere you can also setup the time to say whitch query goes into the slow log

Comment: Created_tmp_disk_tables 38126 on uptime of 3619 is ~10 per second.  or 1 in 4 select statements. Handler status [Handler_read_rnd](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10865/mysql-status-variable-handler-read-rnd-next-is-growing-a-lot#10905) is rather high. Logging log-queries-not-using-indexes is going to be excessive without of `min_examined_row_limit=10000` in your case as a staring point to reduce noise.

Comment: Need `SHOW VARIABLES` to be able to interpret `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS`.  And grab the global status after it has been up for a day (as opposed to barely 1 hour).

Comment: A huge QC + lots of writes = very bad performance.  You were right to lower the query_cache_size.

Comment: The slowlog will help: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog  More on handler numbers:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#handler_counts

Comment: I've just posted a global status as the db is now in a bad state also have changed `query_cache_size` and `query_cache_limit` to 0 prior to this having happened on the previous restart that I did.